# Validation error when seeding in Sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js, faker

I try to seed in Sequelize with huge of data but I got an error "Validation error" when seeding. Please see my code in below.

```
"use strict";

const faker = require("faker");
const User = require("../models").User;

module.exports = {
  up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    let products = [];
    let amount = 100;

    // 50 users
    let users = await User.findAll();
    let userCodes = users.map(user => user.code);
    // output ['x312scAD', 'F32SDcvrW', ...]

    function randomBetween(min, max) {
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
    }

    // image collections from Unsplash.com
    let imagesCollection = [1163637, 190727, 6780963, 1198107, 762960, 1353633, 3321491, 217461, 2203755];
    let imageWidth = 980;
    let imageHeight = 555;

    var uniqueNumbers = [];
    while (uniqueNumbers.length < amount) {
      var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) + 1;
      if (uniqueNumbers.indexOf(r) === -1) uniqueNumbers.push(r);
    }

    while (amount--) {
        let randomCollection = randomBetween(0, imagesCollection.length - 1);
        let randomThumbnail = `https://source.unsplash.com/collection/${imagesCollection[randomCollection]}/${imageWidth}x${imageHeight}/?sig=${uniqueNumbers[amount]}`;

        products.push({
          code: 'abc' + faker.random.number(),
          userCode: userCodes[randomBetween(1, userCodes.length-1)],
          title: faker.lorem.sentence(),
          subtitle: faker.lorem.sentence(),
          description: faker.lorem.paragraphs(),
          categoryId: randomBetween(1, 10),
          thumbnail: randomThumbnail,
          createdAt: new Date(),
          updatedAt: new Date()
        });
      }
      return await queryInterface.bulkInsert("products", products, {});
  }
};
```

PS: User hasMany Products

I think this cause is Async/await but I am new to this kind. Please let's me know where is my fault in this case.

> Can anyone help me to seeding in correct way?

**Here is my product rules in models.Product**

```
code: DataTypes.STRING(12),
userCode: DataTypes.STRING,
title: DataTypes.STRING,
subtitle: DataTypes.STRING,
description: DataTypes.TEXT,
categoryId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
thumbnail: DataTypes.STRING,
createdAt: DataTypes.Date,
updatedAt: DataTypes.Date
```

> **PS: I able to seed sometimes**

Comment: What is your validation rules for `product`?

Comment: In my product model.
Product.belongsTo(models.User, { targetKey: "code", foreignKey: "userCode", as: "user" });

And in my User model
User.hasMany(models.Product, { sourceKey: "code", foreignKey: "userCode", as: "products" });

Comment: thats all validations? how about column type etc.?

Comment: I updated for your question please see detail in above sir.

Comment: for now i can say: `randomBetween` not have to use `await`. Also, you take `userCodes` from `randomBetween(1, 50)`, but does they are 50 in total? I expected to do something like `userCode: userCodes[randomBetween(0, userCodes.length-1)]`

Comment: Ok so as i see the type of `code` is `string` but you give it a number

Comment: and `categoryId` is a `number`, but you give t a `string`

Comment: `created_at` and `updated_at` not exist in the structure, and `isPublished` `publishedAt` exist, but you not pass othing for that

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I updated anything from your suggestions but I got the same error. I updated my code please see above.

Comment: PS: I can seed sometimes. Is it's about Async/await ?

Comment: the `code` is still `number`, while should be a `string`

Comment: Is [number] can save as [string] sir? I am using [random.number()] because I just don't want to create a random string function in my seeder file.

Comment: `"" + faker.random.number()`

Comment: I try `"abc" + faker.random.number()`  but got the same error

Comment: if you able to seed sometimes, its look like sometimes the `random` is out of bound, and sometimes ok. but i  cannot find where. does you have `categoryId` for all 1-10?

Comment: Yep. I have 20 in categories table.

Comment: and they have the according id's? 1-20?

Comment: also, the product `code` should not be `unique`?

Comment: Its unique sir. I defined in migration. `code: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(12),
        allowNull: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        unique: true
      },`

Comment: so it is the problem... when the random generate the same number its not let you to insert

Comment: I have to check it now. Thanks a lot sir :)

Comment: I solved the problem. It because unique number. Big thanks @YosefTukachinsky you are save my life!

Answer (score 1):

My mistake was that I violated the unique email validation in my dummy data, -I sat the email attribute to be unique in my table- yet the data I was providing/seeding had many records with the same email. 
 Once I used new email addresses, it was resolved and the seeds were generated normally.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30907598)